# horizontal scrollbar for ul

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, html-lists

For some reason, I can't prevent the UL and it's LI's from wrapping.
I want the UL's width to be exactly the width of the LI's on one line (without wrapping) and if the UL becomes wider than the nav-div (800px), I want a scrollbar within the nav so I can scroll the LI.

I tried pretty much anything with display, whitespace, width's and height, but I can only get it to work if I give the UL a certain width. This, however, is not an options, since the page is generated and can contain 1-20 LI's.

Does anyone know how to make a scrollbar come up without setting the UL's width?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
     <ul id="navbuttons">
          <li>Some text</li>
          <li>Some text</li>
          ...
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#nav
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div#nav ul li
{
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

try this

```
ul {
   white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
   display:inline;
}
```

Comment: simple as that - just had to get rid of the float!

Comment: yeah but it took me a while before I could get to that you know :P ....apparently browsers won't make text overflowed if they hit with whitespace first ... or something like that I think

and this is true for latest version of OS X Firefox, Safari, Chorome

Comment: If I am doing same thing by using "class" or "id" , then it is not working. Can anyone explain me why it is not working ?

Comment: @YashVekaria mind put up a jsfiddle so we can see why it isn't work for you?

Comment: Can't believe it's simple like that. And I need to add overflow-x: auto to the ul tag as well

Answer (score 14):

You can use `display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;` for the wrapper and `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` for the children.

So, it would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/98cFj/

```
.navbuttons {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #AAA;
}

.navbuttons LI {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And, if you'll need to support IE add this hack in conditional comments to enable `inline-block`s in it:

```
.navbuttons,
.navbuttons LI {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: turns out it was the `float: left` that was giving me trouble, it made the UL height- and width-less - thanks for your help :)

Comment: For me, adding `vertical-align: top;` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: Untested

Would you not just want to set a width for the li item

```
div#nav ul li {    
   margin-right: 15px;     
   float: left;     
   font-size: 12px;     
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 100px;
}
```

And then set the width to a fixed width and overflow on the UL to scroll?

```
div#nav ul {
    width: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This would cause you UL to scroll when your li's went past say 8, is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `width` on the `<ul>` to `inherit` you can use the [`overflow` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) to set the overflow behavior of the element. With the value `scroll`, all of the element's contents will scroll (in both x and y directions) if the height and the width of the contents overflow that of the box:

```
div#nav ul
{
    overflow: scroll;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule:

```
div#nav ul {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```